# Maximum hitting time for random walks on graphs with few edges

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk, planar-graphs

For $x$ and $y$ vertices of a connected graph $G$, let $T_G(x,y)$ denote the expected time before a random walk starting from $x$ reaches $y$. What is the maximum possible value of $T_G(x,y)$ if the graph has to have at most $k$ edges?

I was initially interested in bounding the number of vertices instead of the number of edges. My first guess was that a line graph would be optimal giving $T_G(x,y)=(n-1)^2$ with $n$ vertices. But then I found [Maximum Hitting Time for Random Walks on Graphs](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Epw/papers/maxhit.pdf) which shows that $T_G(x,y)$ can go up to $4n^3/27$ with $n$ vertices.

However the reason I got interested in the initial question was because I was studying grid mazes, and for $n$ large enough, the graph used to get $T_G(x,y)=4n^3/27$ is not possible to recreate with a grid maze, because it is not planar. Since planar graphs have a linear number of edges, I thought the most logical next step would be to try and restrict the number of edges instead of the number of vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very useful identity for the hitting time in a random walk on a graph:
$$
   T_G(x,y) + T_G(y,x) = 2m \cdot R_G(x,y)
$$
where $R_G(x,y)$ is the effective resistance between $x$ and $y$. This effective resistance is at most the distance $d_G(x,y)$: that's what we'd get if there were a unique path between $x$ and $y$ in the graph, and adding more edges can only reduce the effective resistance. In particular, we get an upper bound of $T_G(x,y) \le 2m(n-1)$.

To get close to this upper bound in specific cases, we can take any $k$-vertex graph $H$, and add a path of length $n-k$ starting at a vertex $x \in V(H)$ and ending at a vertex $y$. Here, we have $R_G(x,y) = n-k$ and $T_G(y,x) = (n-k)^2$, so
$$
   T_G(x,y) = 2(|E(H)|+n-k)(n-k) - (n-k)^2.
$$
Even for this specific construction, we can do better by picking $x$ to be a vertex far from the start of the path; I will ignore this.

Your question is about graphs with at most $m$ edges; we can assume that $m$ is less than the number of edges in the extremal lollipop graph, or else we'd just take that graph. In this case, take $k = \frac23n$ and let $H$ be any graph with $m - \frac13n$ edges; we get
$$
   T_G(x,y) = \frac23 mn - \frac19 n^2 
$$
which is off from the upper bound by a constant factor. (To improve the constant a little, reduce $k$ to the least value such that $\binom k2 + n-k \ge m$.)

For planar graphs, the upper bound we get is $T_G(x,y) \le 2m(n-1) \le 6(n-1)(n-2)$. This is not too far off from the value $(n-1)^2$ we get in the case of a path. We can improve on the constant by taking $H$ to be a $k$-vertex triangulation; then we have $$T_G(x,y) = 2(n+2k-6)(n-k) - (n-k)^2 = (n+5k-12)(n-k).$$ This is maximized when $k = \frac25(n+3)$, giving us a graph that contains a hitting time of $T_G(x,y) = \frac95(n-2)^2$. Even this constant is probably not the best possible.

For grid mazes, we can do something similar, taking a large block with as few walls as you're willing to allow, and adding a long path coming out of a corner of that block.

Comment: Do you have a reference on that initial identity?

Comment: It's Theorem 2 in [these lecture notes](https://stanford.edu/~rezab/discrete/Notes/6.pdf), for instance.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I see the point of your comments on the edge-constrained problem. Your construction is to have a graph H containing x, and connect it to y by a path disjoint from H. Let a be the number of edges in H, and b the number of edges in the path. Your conclusion is that the hitting time depends only on those two numbers a and b, in particular we can never do better than when H is a linear graph, in which case the entire graph is just linear with x in the middle somewhere. This is clearly worse than the case of a linear graph with x and y at opposite ends...

Comment: ...so all we have shown is that for such graphs, the hitting time never exceeds $m^2$, $m$ being the total number of edges in the graph. And that's lower than the bound you got from the resistance inequality anyway. In other words, it seems to me that all you needed to do was construct the linear graph on m edges, and that would have gotten you closer to the resistance inequality bound. The interesting question to me is whether we can do better than that, i.e. find an m-edge graph with greater than $m^2$ hitting time.

Comment: @JackM I am solving the problem where the number of vertices *and* the number of edges is known. You are looking at a different problem: where the number of edges $m$ is fixed, but the number of vertices is variable.

Comment: That being said, for your question, my argument still shows that the optimal hitting time is between $m^2$ and $2m^2$, so it's only the constant to worry about.